# why chrome proxy addon change request

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension

I am doing web develop and I use chrome proxy addons like switchyomega to do quick proxy setting.

The proxy server I am using is based on node express, which is running on localhost 3000

I noticed that when I turn on proxy (which redirects my web page request to nodejs express which runs on localhost 3000 ), the request object received by express changed a little bit

e.g.

If I type http://localhost:3000 in address bar, without proxy addon turned on, in node express I get a request object with url property value "/"
But when I turn on proxy, I get a request object with url property value "localhost:3000"

Any idea what is going on when the chrome proxy addon is on ? Thanks.

Comment: Might be a bug in Chrome. Care to report on https://crbug.com ?

Comment: thx and I just opened one.